# How do I do this exact same thing, but wtih an arbitrary number of nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following code in an xslt.

```
<xsl:sort
    select="concat( 
        (com:prices/com:price[1]), 
        (com:prices/com:price[2]), 
        (com:prices/com:price[3]), 
        (com:prices/com:price[4]))" />
```

The problem is that its hard coded for only 4 prices, when there could be an indefinite amount of prices.  Whats the syntax for concatenating all available price nodes?

Apologies for the noob question, but xslt is one of my worst/least experienced languages and all of the examples I've found online seem overly complicated.

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: Also, your post lacks a lot of information. To be able to reproduce the issue we need: a sample XML input, a full XSLT stylesheet. Then, the actual output XML and a description of the output you expect. Perhaps you do not need sort, you never know.

Comment: Are you sure about this? It does not seem reasonable to sort by a (textual) concatenation of prices.

Comment: The prices are already sorted, and concatenating them together is just a means to get a sort key.  I do need to sort on the value of the Price and a an attribute of price, but if i can do one i can do the other.  Unfortunately i'm not able to show more code than what i've shown.  I can dummy up an example but in the past have been yelled at about how contrived my example was...

Comment: Well, the thing is that when sorting alphabetically (in ascending order), prices "2" & "3" will come **after** prices "10" & "11".

Comment: Yup.  The xml being fed into the xslt is not deterministically generated.(At least in regards to the ordering)  The prices will be unique every time (in my case).  If I sort by price then the same unordered xml gets turned into ordered xml, which is what i need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use XSLT 2.0 then doing `<xsl:sort select="string-join(com:prices/com:price, '')"/>` would concatenate all price elements.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks.   I'de seen this function, but I didn't know you could apply it with a single select.